# python script not terminating after timeout in ZMQ recv()

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, zeromq, pyzmq

This is my first time working with IPC so far and I have written this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVTIMEO, 2000)
socket.connect ("ipc:///tmp/something")
socket.send(b"123")
try:
    message = socket.recv()
except:
    print("DEBUG!")
    message = None
```

When my server script is running ( it simply sends an answer ) everything is working fine.

But when the **`.recv()`**-call timeouts ( e.g. because there is no server running ), the script won't terminate after the "DEBUG!"-print and I have to manually stop it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I tried disconnecting and closing the socket, but it doesn't change anything.

When I put the whole script into a function and call it, I get the following error on **`KeyboardInterrupt:`**

```
^CException ignored in: <bound method Context.__del__ of <zmq.sugar.context.Context object at 0x7f16a36d5128>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/sugar/context.py", line 46, in __del__
    self.term()
  File "zmq/backend/cython/context.pyx", line 136, in zmq.backend.cython.context.Context.term (zmq/backend/cython/context.c:2339)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 12, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc (zmq/backend/cython/context.c:3207)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I'm running Python 3.6.1 and version 16.0.2 of the PyZMQ module on an Arch Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### May adopt this as a standard ZeroMQ infrastructure setup policy:

A default value of the **`LINGER`** attribute forces the `socket` instance to wait upon an attempt to `.close()`. So set this to **`0`** so as to avoid this feature / behaviour right upon instantiation, not to finally hang upon a termination.

```
import zmq
nIOthreads = 2                           # ____POLICY: set 2+: { 0: non-blocking, 1: blocking, 2: ...,  }
context = zmq.Context( nIOthreads )      # ____POLICY: set several IO-datapumps

socket  = context.socket( zmq.PAIR )
socket.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER,      0 )  # ____POLICY: set upon instantiations
socket.setsockopt( zmq.AFFINITY,    1 )  # ____POLICY: map upon IO-type thread
socket.setsockopt( zmq.RCVTIMEO, 2000 )

socket.connect( "ipc:///tmp/something" )
socket.send( b"123" )
try:
    message = socket.recv()
except:
    print( "DEBUG!" )
    message = None
finally:
    socket.close()                       # ____POLICY: graceful termination
    context.term()                       # ____POLICY: graceful termination
```

Answer (score 0):

user3666197's answer is correct, in the sense that `socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)` will solve the problem you described.

But per [the docs](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket) the PAIR socket is only intended to be used for inter-thread communication in a single process.  Specifically, it won't reconnect the connection is broken.

It may work correctly via ipc (I've never tried), but I recommend using a different socket type.